# How to find an example of a linear transformation such that $TS$ is bijective but neither $S$ nor $T$ is bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I think we can find two dependent matrices that forms a linearly independent matrices when multiplied by each other. But I can't find one.

Comment: In finite dimensions, if $det(TS)\neq 0\Rightarrow \det T,det S\neq 0$ where $T,S\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$

Comment: Think about maps $\Bbb R^m \overset{S}{\to} \Bbb R^n \overset{T}{\to} \Bbb R^m$ with $m < n$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the maps $S:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ and $T:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
S(x) = (x,0)\\
T(x,y) = x
$$